# Reading rows as one-dimensional array from textfile using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a text-file, containing a large number of rows. Each row has 4096 integer values.

```
500 501 300 400 ------------------------------------------------------------
300 400 600 700 -----
501 407 603 771 ------------------------------------------------------------
382 659 889 700 -----
so on
```

what I am trying to do is to read this file as a one-dimensional array using numpy. I couldn't do it using simple loadtxt as it requires same number of column.
Any suggestions on how can I do it? My end goal is to manipulate this array to insert certain values.

you can get more detail from my code here,

```
from sys import argv
import numpy as np 
script, PhilFile = argv
intxt = open(PhilFile)
invalues = intxt.read()

invalues = invalues.replace(' ', '\n')

adc = np.asarray(invalues)
print adc

N_CHANS = 5

N_SAMPS = 256

H = len(adc)/N_SAMPS

N = 0

header = np.array([666,777,888,999])

for l in range(0,H) :
   adc = np.insert(adc, [N]*header.size, header)

   N += 258

print adc

np.savetxt("test1.txt", adc)
```

I supply textfile as an argument, currently, I am getting an error as,

```
 H = len(adc)/N_SAMPS 
 TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: I don't understand.  You say each row has `4096 integer values`, but can't use `loadtxt` because of differing number of columns.  Those are conflicting statements.  OK, so you read the file and replace nl.  But where do you split the line(s) into strings representings those integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your error with:

```
In [596]: np.array('1 2 3 4 5')
Out[596]: array('1 2 3 4 5', dtype='<U9')
In [597]: len(_)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-597-556fcc1c5d2a> in <module>()
----> 1 len(_)

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Constructing an array from a single string produces a 0d, single element array.

You have to first split the string:

```
In [598]: np.array('1 2 3 4 5'.split())
Out[598]: array(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], dtype='<U1')
In [599]: np.array('1 2 3 4 5'.split(),int)
Out[599]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

You printed `adc`.  Didn't you notice that it wasn't a numeric array?  I strongly recommend developing code like this step by step in an interactive session (I use `ipython`).  It helps catch inconsistencies like this.

Comment: Thanks! I can see the problem now, I took your approach and the code is now working correctly.